# Should i use hybrid app which has user authentication and store sessions?

Tags: sencha-touch, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi I'm new to hybrid app development, i'm trying to develop an hybrid app using Sencha, which has features like user login, store user details in local(client), and consume rest apis. AFAIK its not possible  to make a POST request(CORS) and cookie storage don't work in mobile.
 So whats the workaround to it OR should i really be using the hybrid at all

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I have a tutorial series available on building a Sencha Touch Login with a PHP backend if you would like to check it out: http://www.joshmorony.com/part-1-sencha-touch-email-facebook-log-in-system-with-php-mysql-backend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple ajax request will work, you don't need CORS nor JSONP if you package the app with cordova or phonegap. Once app is packaged you don't have cross domain restrictions.

Yeah go for it with Sencha Touch.